# How to insert an unknown value to enum type field in solr

Tags: java, enums, solr

I have a requirement where docs need to be sorted based on an enum field. Let's say - field name is Status and enum values are - CREATED, SUBMITTED, DELIVERED. The problem is whenever an unknown value is inserted into solr, solr throws an exception. Can anyone please share how an unknown value can be inserted into solr and sorted in alphabetical order?
Example: Unknown values are UNKNOWN1, UNKNOWN2, then sorting would be -

```
CREATED
SUBMITTED
DELIVERED
UNKNOWN1
UNKNOWN2
```

Comment: EnumField types are, by definition, a closed set, you'll always get an exception if you try to index an unknown value. Can you, for example, add a 'UNKNOWN' value to the enum and add a little bit of logic at index time (if the value to index is not in the set then index it as `UNKNOWN`)?

Comment: Yeah, that is something which I have implemented as of now. UNKNOWN doesn't need to be added in this case. The only problem is that unknown values can not be sorted.

Comment: I see. Well, in that case, i would probably add another (text) field and sort from it. But maybe you should review the need of having a EnumType on a field where you essentially need to store more values than the predetermined set. Also note that you can actually add values to the end of the set but that's probably not an option for you since it's a configuration.